# Invalid markup with all my div classes when using php in dreamweaver

Tags: php, dreamweaver, markup, navbar

First things first: I'm no pro. 
I just started slapping together a sub site for my company using Dreamweaver CS6 and learning (crash coursing) a lot about HTML - and I know there's going to be multiple pages that my navbar is going to constantly be changed to link pages to. So to save time instead of going to each page one by one to keep the site updated, I've created my navbar on a seperate file (../swseries/cssmenu.php) - and it works perfectly.

Taking this navbar, putting it within the code of my calendar.php page causes ALL my div classes to be marked up as invalid within the source code:

```
<div class="cssmenudiv">
<?php include 'cssmenu.php'; ?>
</div>
```

In design mode, the `</head>` tag is marked invalid. But whenever I put it onto the server and view it, everything pulls up correctly (I believe). I guess the question is, am I actually doing anything wrong, or is dreamweaver being incorrect? 
Here's the address, keep in mind, it's very cut and dry at the moment: 
http://track21houston.com/swseries/calendar.php
Any tips are appreciated! *(in b4 stop using dw)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because in cssmenu.php you must be having `<html>` or `<head>` or `<body>` tags those may be already present in your current file with the `<div>` tag having `include` statement.

Comment: Thank you! I briefly thought that would be the problem, but in the back of my mind, I was thinking it was required to include the HEAD and BODY within the page I was requesting. All my styles and scripts still work as well - awesome.